# return to current page in pagination using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

index.js

```
const Users = () => {
 const [valid] = useState([]);
 const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

const TestSync = async () => {
 const res = await axios.get(`https://rekko.dev.devserver.in/dashboard-users`, {})
 setUsers(res.data.response.userRecords || [])
}
 useEffect(() => {
  TestSync()
 }, [])

 // Data to be rendered using pagination.
 const todos = users;
 const todosPerPage = 10;
 const [activePage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);  =====>>> if here page number is set dyanimically to current page will solve problem

// Logic for displaying current todos
const indexOfLastTodo = activePage * todosPerPage;
const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
const currentTodos = todos.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

const handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
 setCurrentPage(pageNumber)
};

return (
      <>
        <CRow>
          <CCol xl={12}>
            <CCard>
              <CCardHeader>
                <strong> <span className='dashHead'> Users </span> </strong>
              </CCardHeader>
              <CCardBody>
                <CDataTable
                  items={currentTodos}
                  fields={[
                    {
                      key: 'name', _classes: 'font-weight-bold'
                    }, 'Joining Date', 'Registration Type', 'actions'
                  ]}
                  hover
                  striped
                  scopedSlots={{
                    'name':
                      (item) => (
                        <td className='width'>
                          {item.name}
                        </td>
                      ),
                    'Joining Date':
                      (item) => (
                        <td>
                          {item.createdAt}
                        </td>
                      ),
                    'actions':
                      (item) => (
                        <td>
                          <Link to={(`/user/${item.id}`)} >
                            <CIcon className="text-success" name="cil-people" />
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                      )
                  }}
                />
                <div className="pagination">
                  <Pagination
                    activePage={activePage}
                    itemsCountPerPage={10}
                    totalItemsCount={todos.length}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={2}
                    onChange={handlePageChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </CCardBody>
            </CCard>
          </CCol>
        </CRow>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Users
```

Everything is working fine but what I want that if I go into detail of any user after that it returns to the first page as by default active page is set to 1. What I want is it shows 10 records on one page and if I am on the second page and I open detail of any user and return back it goes back to 1 page basically the solution can be if the active page set to 2 if I am on the second page and 3 if I am on the third page then it will solve the problem but don't know-how. I am stuck on this for the last 2 days any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can handle page number through redux.

Comment: How can't i handle without redux as i have not used redux in this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a complete solution but can give you some direction. you can place your page number in url by changing your route in react-router as follow

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/userslist/:page-number" component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

and access page number by

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
let { page-number } = useParams();
...
const [activePage, setCurrentPage] = useState(page-number);
```

in this way suppose you are on page 2 like `/userslist/2` and navigate to specific users details page `user/23` and return. it will load data of page number 2 because of url.